# Can multiple Checklists on a Trello card be re-arranged?

Tags: trello

If I have multiple (independent) checklists on a card, is it possible to change the order in which they appear? I know I can change the order of items within a checklist.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming from the future, you can now re-order checklists within cards.